# Linked List implementation Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a data model where there are `Document` entities, which need to be in a defined order to each other. Think of an article that has sections which build up on one another.

*Example:*

```
Document1 -> Document3 -> Document2 -> Document6 -> Document5 -> Document4
```

I was trying to implement a `linked list` to achieve that. Unfortunately `EF Core 2.0` does not support recursive queries. Therefore I needed a parent entity, named `DocumentCollection`. The requirement is to be able to get the `Documents` in the predefined order.

Please suggest improvements or alternative approaches.

---

## Entity definitions

`DocumentCollection` model:

```
public class DocumentCollection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }

    public DocumentCollection()
    {
        Documents = new HashSet<Document>();
    }
}
```

`Document` model:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties

    public int CollectionId { get; set; }
    public DocumentCollection Collection { get; set; }

    public int? PredecessorId { get; set; }
    public Document Predecessor { get; set; }

    public int? SuccessorId { get; set; }
    public Document Successor { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

`DbContext` relationship mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasKey(product => product.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(product => product.Name).HasMaxLength(70);

    modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentCollection>()
        .HasKey(collection => collection.Id);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().HasKey(document => document.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().Property(document => document.Name).HasMaxLength(70);

    modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentCollection>()
        .HasMany(collection => collection.Documents)
        .WithOne(document => document.Collection)
        .HasPrincipalKey(collection => collection.Id)
        .HasForeignKey(document => document.CollectionId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
        .HasOne(document => document.Predecessor)
        .WithOne(document => document.Successor)
        .HasPrincipalKey<Document>(principal => principal.Id)
        .HasForeignKey<Document>(dependent => dependent.PredecessorId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
        .HasOne(document => document.Successor)
        .WithOne(document => document.Predecessor)
        .HasPrincipalKey<Document>(principal => principal.Id)
        .HasForeignKey<Document>(dependent => dependent.SuccessorId);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

---

## Service used to manage the entities:

```
public class DocumentService
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;
    public DbSet<Document> Entities => _context.Documents;

    public DocumentService(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [...]
}
```

Creating an initial `Document`:

```
public async Task<Document> AddDocument(Document document)
{
    document.Collection = new DocumentCollection();
    var result = await Entities.AddAsync(document);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return result.Entity;
}
```

Adding `Document` to a specific position:

```
public async Task<Document> AddDocumentSuccessor(int parentId, Document document)
{
    var predecessor = await Entities
        .Include(entity => entity.Successor)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(entity => entity.Id == parentId);

    if (predecessor == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    document.CollectionId = predecessor.CollectionId;
    var result = await Entities.AddAsync(document);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    var newEntity = result.Entity;

    newEntity.PredecessorId = predecessor.Id;
    if (predecessor.Successor != null)
    {
        newEntity.SuccessorId = predecessor.SuccessorId;
    }

    predecessor.SuccessorId = newEntity.Id;
    if (predecessor.Successor != null)
    {
        predecessor.Successor.PredecessorId = newEntity.Id;
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return result.Entity;
}
```

Getting an ordered list of related `Document` entities:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Document>> GetRelatedDocuments(int id)
{
    var collectionId = await Entities
        .Where(entity => entity.Id == id)
        .Select(entity => entity.CollectionId)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (collectionId == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var result = await Entities
        .Where(entity => entity.CollectionId == collectionId)
        .Select(entity => new Document
        {
            Id = entity.Id,
            Name = entity.Name,
            CollectionId = entity.CollectionId,
            PredecessorId = entity.PredecessorId,
            SuccessorId = entity.SuccessorId
        })
        .ToArrayAsync();

    return OrderByHierarchy(result);
}
```

Method used for sorting:

```
private static IEnumerable<Document> OrderByHierarchy(
    IReadOnlyCollection<Document> documents)
{
    if (documents.Count == 0)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var dict = documents.ToDictionary
    (
        entity => entity.PredecessorId ?? 0, 
        entity => entity
    );

    var key = 0;
    Document document;

    do
    {
        document = dict[key];
        yield return document;
        key = document.Id;
    }
    while (document.SuccessorId != null);
}
```

Comment: This could have been so simple if instead of having parent/next-ids you'd have just created a property like `Ordinal` with the index of the document in the list.

Comment: @t3chb0t I thought about this as well. The thing that I found bad about this, is that when inserting new `Document` entities, I probably have to update allot of them at once.

Answer (score 1):

I find you should stick to the same naming convention of the original [`LinkedListNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754(v=vs.110).aspx). This means that you should have a `Preview` and `Next` properties and not `Predecessor` and `Successor` respecitively.

I then would implement these two in another class, e.g. `LinkedEntityNode`:

```
public class LinkedEntityNode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? NextId { get; set; }
    public int? PreviousId { get; set; }
}
```

and put this in a separate table.

Then let the document reference the node:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? NodeId { get; set; }   

    #region Navigation Properties

    public LinkedEntityNode Node { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

It would require a couple of adjustments to the models and to the sorting and finding logic but this way you could implement it once and for all and use it in any other project to link all kinds of stuff this way. Not just the `Document` entity.

I also think you don't need the collection type because as soon as you know one document (a node), you can rebuild it from there.

Comment: In fact I'm going to solve it this way because I have a couple of uses for it already :-)

Comment: Would you think it might be a better idea to inherit from `LinkedEntityNode` because `EF Core` requires you to define `one to one` relationships with `navigation properties` on both related models?

Comment: @SebastianKrogull I'm not sure but I'd rather not. I treat the `LinkedEntityNode` as an _extension_ to the current model. It is possible that entities already are derived from another (domain) type. In this case it wouldn't be possible to link them anymore because multiple inheritance isn't possible in C#.